# Joining table of single house layer to zone layer by location using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join

I have a layer which shows all the single house polygon. I also have a zone layer which shows the boundary of different regions.

I would like to see which region each single house polygon is in, like having a field in single house polygon attribute table, stating which region does it fall to.

If the polygon falls under 2 regions' boundaries, i want it to belong in the region with the larger section of the house polygon.

Tried spatial join however there are no matching fields to do so

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [Spatial Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) does not require a shared field between the input data. It is not join by attribute which requires shared Fields.

The solution is to use Spatial Join and use the Building polygon as input and the boundary as Join Feature. In the Match option use `Have their center in` selected as you can see below:

[image]

From the help above:

> **HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN** —The features in the join features will be matched if a target feature's center falls within them. The center of
>   the feature is calculated as follows: for polygon and multipoint the
>   geometry's centroid is used, and for line input the geometry's
>   midpoint is used.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I see now that they have spatially joined, however is it possible for me to see which zone each house poly is in, in the attribute table of house poly? (There is a field in zone layer which specify the zone names)

Comment: @Dixbe if the zone boundary has a field name and you did spatial join, then the field name of that zone will be added to the house poly. This means that specific house is located in that zone poly.

Comment: sorry im relatively new, i see the fields in the house layer, however all the fields from zone layer are stated as "null", is there anything i can do in this case?

Comment: @Dixbe Do the house polygon and zone polygon have the same projection (spatial reference)?

Comment: yes they do, both projected and geographic coordinate systems are the same